# Redirect blog subdomain to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've recently redesigned a site and need to redirect posts from http://blog.example.co.uk to http://www.example.co.uk.  My .htaccess is currently:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co\.uk  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.uk$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But alas!  This isn't working.

Any advice is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co\.uk$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to actually go into the subdomain in the hosting package and redirect it this way.